# Mockito: @InjectMocks (OK) vs constructor of mocked objects (NPE)

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

Here is the class that should be tested:

```
public class UserService {
    private final UserDAO userDAO;
    private final TransactionManager transactionManager;

    public UserService(UserDAO userDAO, TransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    public boolean isUserEmailUnique(HttpServletRequest req, Connection connection) {
        User user = transactionManager //---- NPE if no InjectMocks was done -----
                .doInTransaction(connection, (con) ->
                userDAO.getUserByEmail(con, req.getParameter(Attributes.EMAIL)));

        return Objects.isNull(user);
    }
```

Here is the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Mock HttpServletRequest mockedReq;
    @Mock TransactionManager mockedTransactionManager;
    @Mock Connection mockedConnection;
    
    UserService userService; // QUESTION IS ABOUT THAT OBJECT

    @Test
    public void ifSuchUserWasNotFound_ThenEmailIsUnique() {
        doReturn(new User()).when(mockedTransactionManager).doInTransaction(any(Connection.class), any(TransactionOperation.class));
        assertFalse(userService.isUserEmailUnique(mockedReq, mockedConnection));

        doReturn(null).when(mockedTransactionManager).doInTransaction(any(Connection.class), any(TransactionOperation.class));
        assertTrue(userService.isUserEmailUnique(mockedReq, mockedConnection));
    }
```

If I inject mocks into the tested `userService` like shown below, this test works fine.

```
@InjectMocks UserService userService;
```

But if I create a new instance and pass mocked objects to the constructor like shown below, a NullPointerException about `transactionManager` is thrown inside the tested class

```
// no @InjectMocks
UserService userService = new UserService(mockedUserDAO, mockedTransactionManager);
```

Isn't it supposed to be the same thing? Maybe I'm a bad reader, but the official [article](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) doesn't say `@InjectMocks` is supposed to do something special which is not available for basic constructor.

Any ideas why a mocked object passed to the constructor is still null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from the order of events:

```
UserService userService = new UserService(mockedUserDAO, mockedTransactionManager);
```

creates the instance as part of creating the test class instance, but mockito hasn't ran yet so `mockedUserDAO` and `mockedTransactionManager` are null.

Move the instance creation to a set up method:

```
UserService userService;

@Before
public void prepareTest() {
    userService = new UserService(mockedUserDAO, mockedTransactionManager);
}
```

Comment: Or `HttpServletRequest mockedReq = mock(HttpServletRequest.class)`